# Javascript and AJAX trough outside function

Tags: javascript, ajax, wait

```
function ajax_request(destination_full_url) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("response: \n" + xmlhttp.responseText);
            return xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", destination_full_url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}



    function third_party_function(obj) {
       var response
       response = ajax_request("info.php?keyword=obj.value");
       alert(response);         
    }


<textarea onkeypress="third_party_function(this);"></textarea>
```

First comes off message box "underfined" one second after comes off message box with ajax request.

Question is why it runs alert(response); before finishing the previous step and how i make it wait untill ajax_request() function finished before going to next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because ajax is asynchronous and runs in background by default, you can make it synchronous by changing from

xmlhttp.open("GET", destination_full_url, true);

to

xmlhttp.open("GET", destination_full_url, false);

=== update ===

```
function ajax_request(destination_full_url, callback){
.....
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("response: \n" + xmlhttp.responseText);
           callback(xmlhttp.responseText);

        }
    }
...
}

....


function third_party_function(obj) {
       ajax_request("info.php?keyword=obj.value", function(response){alert(response) });

    }
```

Comment: How can i convert my current ajax function to use method POST?

Comment: xmlhttp.open("POST", destination_full_url, false); :)

Comment: That was simple :). Thanks. Also i checked with FireBug and it makes 2 requests to info.php second keep running, i only have "echo 'done' in that php file.

Comment: that is cause first will check header for 200 or 304 response. 200 will ready body then and 304 will get response from cache. I think :)

Comment: First one that finish is 302 second one that runs forever is 200

Comment: hmmm 302, you are redirected somewhere... use `console.log(xmlhttp.readyState, xmlhttp.status, xmlhttp.responseText);` before line  `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {`  You should be able to see what is happening in firebug

Comment: Ok never mind there actually was one include in info.php that has redirect ... removing redirect fixes problem.

Comment: One more question how i pass variable if i change method to post?

Comment: And i am still getting UNDEFINED on alert(response); however now it shows after the popup inside ajax_request() function

Comment: It works when i do document.response = xmlhttp.responseText; and then alert(document.response), why it does not work with return?

Comment: with changes I made in my answer you don't have to set ajax synchronous anymore

Comment: thx m8, but how do i post variable now i cannot use ?keyword=obj.value since i use POST instead of GET

Comment: in xhhtprequest.send("keyword=" + obj.value);